# How would I pass a string to a function argument defined as const unsigned char*?

Tags: c++, string

I copied Base64 encode/decode functions from Stack Overflow. The decode function works great. My problem is with the encode. I get the following error using Visual Studio 2022:

```
error C2664: 'std::string Base64_encode(const unsigned char *,size_t)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const _Elem *' to 'const unsigned char *'
```

Code snippet:

```
    string Base64_decode(const void* data, const size_t len);
    string Base64_encode(const unsigned char* src, size_t len);
    
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
       string lsOriginal;
       string lsEncoded;
       string lsDecoded;
    
       lsEncoded = Base64_encode(lsOriginal.c_str(), lsOriginal.size());
    
       lsDecoded = Base64_decode(lsBase64.c_str(), lsBase64.size());
```

I tried using reinterpret_cast but I couldn't get it to work. I've never used it before so I'm struggling to get it to compile.

Comment: You could change the base64 functions to accept a `const std::string&` instead. That would be a more C++ way to do things.

Comment: "I tried using reinterpret_cast but I couldn't get it to work." You should show what you tried and what the result was. Note that `const unsigned char` (as in your question title) is not the same as `const unsigned char*` (as in your code). The `*` makes all the difference in the world.

Comment: Those functions look like they're named backward. You encode binary data into Base64 text, and then decode Base64 text into binary data. Those signatures don't really fit that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that `std::string::c_str` returns a `const char*` and your function `Base64_encode` takes an `const unsigned char*`but there is **no implicit conversion** from a `const char*` to `const unsigned char*`.

To solve this you could use `reinterpret_cast` as shown below:

```
Base64_encode(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(lsOriginal.c_str()), lsOriginal.size());
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ollfizAdnX)

---

You can even change the functions to so that their first parameter is a `const std::string&`. Then there will be no need to have the second parameter corresponding to size since we can use `std::string::size` member function.

```
//------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv------------------->first parameter is lvalue reference to const std::string
std::string Base64_encode(const std::string& src)
//----------------------------------------------^-------------->no need for having second parameter
{
    return "fd";//return something
}
    
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::string lsOriginal = "fdfd";
   std::string lsEncoded;
   
//--------------------------vvvvvvvvv---------------------->pass the original string by reference
  lsEncoded = Base64_encode(lsOriginal);
  
}
```

Comment: The reinterpret_cast worked, thanks for that.